# How to extend sidebar.js to perform action on Qty change in Minicart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart, qty

I added a text field Box in minicart that need to perform some calculation on keyup to update Qty.

I Added box field by modifying

> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

Now I want to extend sidebar.js, To perform action on Knockout.js so that I update the Qty on keyup

> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

I am not sure how to do this.

I created a module and extended the sidebar.js in requirejs-config.js, its not working.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar': 'new_ConfigProductDynamicName/js/sidebar',
        }
    }
};
```

I can see keyup of Qty to display update button in sidebar.js, I am not sure what will come at this.options.item.qty I am trying to do console.

```
 events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                console.log(this.options.item.qty);
                self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };
```

**How can I create a keyup function for the text field Box I created and perform action to update the Qty of that particular product in Mincart**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can follow below steps to solve the issue you have.

**step 1:**
update Box input html in the file ***checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html***  as below.

```
<div class="details-qty box">
    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Box', attr: {
                    for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qtybox'}"></label>
    <input data-bind="attr: {
        id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qtybox',
        'data-cart-item': item_id,
        'data-item-boxqty': qty,
        'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
        }, value: qty"
        type="number"
        size="4"
        class="item-qty cart-item-qtybox">
</div>
```

**step 2:**
update your modules **requirejs-config.js** for [mixins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html).

File : **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {    
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar': 'new_ConfigProductDynamicName/js/sidebar',: true},
        },        

    }
};
```

**step 3:**
Please update the JS file for the js component '**new_ConfigProductDynamicName/js/sidebar**'

File : **sidebar.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',    
    'uiComponent'
], function($, Component) {
    'use strict'; 
    return function(target) {
    return $.widget('mage.sidebar', $.mage.sidebar, {
        options: {
            isRecursive: true,
            item: {
                'qtybox':':input.cart-item-qtybox',
            }
        },       

        _showItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
                itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');
            var qtyBoxElemId =  'cart-item-'+itemId+'-qtybox';
            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
                var boxQty = elem.val() / 5 ;
                $("#"+qtyBoxElemId).val(boxQty);

            } else if (elem.val() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            } else {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            }
        },

    });
  }
});
```

**step 4:** Now run below CLI command from your Magento root to clean static content and cache refresh

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please suggest or answer for this question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313402/need-to-add-a-guest-checkout-button-in-authentication-popup-magneto-2